# Mustache prefix:classpath:/templates/ throwing 404

Tags: java, spring-boot

I do have a strange problem here. The following configuration working fine in eclipse when I run from eclipse. When I build jar and run from that throwing 404 for the following request mapping. Further debug gave me error like `Null modelAndView found`

I have configured mustache in my application.yml as follows

```
spring:   
  profiles:
    active: dev

mustache:   
  prefix:classpath:/templates/   
  suffix:.html
```

I have the following folder structure

[image]

My controller

```
@Controller
public class MainController {

    @RequestMapping("/home1")
    ModelAndView home1() {
          ModelAndView modelAndView =new ModelAndView();
          Map<String,Object> modelObjects = new LinkedHashMap<String,Object>();
          modelAndView.addObject("modelObjects", modelObjects);
          modelAndView.setViewName("/home");
        return modelAndView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm the stupidest man in the world.

`modelAndView.setViewName("/home");` I should not have `/` at the beginning. Somehow it's working fine when I run from target, but not in jar.